# MAP: estimate 2 parameters

Tags: probability, bayesian, normal-distribution, map-estimation

I have some data x and I want to estimate the mu and sigma of this data according to model $x \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ where I have priors $\mu \sim N(0, 1)$ and $\sigma \sim \Gamma(1, 1)$.

Assume $\theta = \{\mu, \sigma\}$

I want to use **maximum a posteriori** (MAP) using Bayes theorem

$p(\theta|x) = p(x|\theta)p(\theta)/p(x)$

but I am struggling to get the $p(\theta)$ right, is it the product of the 2 separate priors?

Is $p(\theta) = p(\mu)p(\sigma)$?

Comment: If they're assumed to be independent, yes.

Comment: since the mean and sd priors should not depend on each other, I guess I can assume independence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the RVs $\mu,\sigma$ are assumed to be independent, which is typical but not necessary, you can write $$p(\theta)=p(\mu,\sigma)=p(\mu)p(\sigma)$$

As a side note, RVs have dependence or independence, not the priors because they are just marginal PDFs.